# Axios with VUE - Request header field content-encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to build a quick webapp for fun based on League of Legends API.

Some calls are working for some I'm getting

"Request header field content-encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

I read some similar questions, and I have tried every method to add headers but I can't get out.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 getLast10Games() {
  axios
    .get(
      "https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/" +
        this.puuid +
        "?start=0&count=10&api_key" +
        this.apiKey,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
          "X-App-Rate-Limit": "20:1,100:120",
          "X-App-Rate-Limit-Count": "1:1,1:120",
          "X-Method-Rate-Limit": "500:10",
          "X-Method-Rate-Limit-Count": "1:10",
          "X-Riot-Edge-Trace-Id": "d31c72cb-7d79-4a8b-bf2c-56218c68a47f",
          "Content-Encoding": "gzip",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
          "DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range",
          "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "Content-Length,Content-Range",
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the headers to your axios request. While some of them can be used to tell the seever certain hints about your request, most of these are only used as **Response Headers**, meaning headers that would be returned by the server. Try removing the entire headers object and making your request again.

Comment: Hello, even without any headers i'm getting CORS error :(

Comment: Your API key may need to be configured to allow the hostname of your site. Check with Riot Games for an option to add an allowed hostname to your API key